# I Cannot Install CentOS7,4

Tags: centos

I bought a new computer with AMZ Ryzen Threadripper 3970X CPU without pre-installed operating system. I first installed CentOS8.4 and it worked. But later when I tried to re-install version7.4, I kept getting this error.

The 4th line is: CPU 3 PID 1 Comm swapper/O Not tained 3.10.0-1160.e17.x86_64 #1

Last two lines: Kernel panic - not syncing:Fatal exception
Kernel Offset : 0xb .......

Is it because my hardware in not compatible with CentOS7?[image]

Comment: 1. Since Centos 8 works and Centos 7.x doesn't, I would guess that the kernel for Centos 7 is too old.  Kernel 3.10.0 is ancient (June 2013 - years before even the first Zen CPU).  2. How did you even get a 3970x to fit in an Asus TUF Gaming X570-PLUS motherboard?  X570 is an AM4 socket chipset, while the Threadripper 3970X requires a TRX-40 socket....they're not even remotely compatible.  Are you sure you've got a 3970x CPU and not a Ryzen 9 CPU like a 3950/3950x or 5900/5950x?

Comment: Thanks, I checked the invoice and I think the right version is AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16C32T 3.4-4.9GHz. You're very right about the second point. About the first point is: I read on the forum that centos8 stops working by the end of this year and centos7 will keep working until three years later. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Centos 8 will not "stop working" at the end of the year.  It'll stop being supported, but it won't magically just stop working on a certain date.   If you want to stay with something like RHEL/Centos, then use [Rocky Linux](https://rockylinux.org/) instead, it's a continuation of the Centos goal of being a community version of RHEL.   Otherwise switch to something like Debian or Ubuntu.  They will never be dumped by their parent corporation when it's no longer convenient (100% certain for Debian because there is no corporation, it's a community distro.  99.9% certain for Ubuntu).

Comment: @cas, Debian/Ubuntu certainly declare End-of-Life for their distributions at some point. Yes, they'll go on running; but no updates (not even for very critical bugs), no tracking of newer hardware, ...

Comment: @vonbrand Huh? I never said they didn't declare EOL (Debian, for example, only supports stable and oldstable, which can be a very long time given debian stable's release schedule of "when it's ready").  I said they won't dump their community distribution when it's no longer convenient, as RH has done with Centos, turning it into an experimental branch for free alpha testing.

Comment: CentOS 7.4 : Year 2017 . ......... The current updated CentOS 7.9 (kernel 3.10.0-1160 with "year 2020 drivers") may work http://ftp.fau.de/centos/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/

Comment: Another alternative if you want to use CentOS 8 is to switch over to CentOS 8-stream, which will continue to be supported as long as RHEL8 will be supported.